space of compactly supported functions $C_c^\infty(R^n)$ is continuously embedded in Schwartz space $S(R^n)$
I am learning Schwartz space by reading Hintz's Microlocal analysis.
In this note, Schwartz space $S(R^n)$ is the set of smooth functions in $R^n$ with
$$\|\phi\|_k := \sup_{x \in R^n, |\alpha| + |\beta|\leq k} |x^\alpha D^\beta \phi(x) | <\infty.$$
Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are multi indices. I agree that the set $C_c^\infty(R^n)$ of compactly supported smooth functions is in the Schwartz space $S(R^n)$. However, I have no idea how to show that $C_c^\infty(R^n)$ is continuously embedded in $S(R^n)$.
I first choose a sequence of functions $\{f_k\}$ converging to $f$ in $C_c^\infty(R^n)$. That is, for any $\epsilon >0$ there is $N$ such that for $n \geq N$
$$\sup_{x \in R^n} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon.$$
Now, we want to show that for each $k\geq 0$, $\|f_n \to f\|_k \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
The above sup norm convergence implies $\|\cdot \|_0$ convergence. However, I am not sure, how to show the other norms $\|\cdot \|_k$ are convergent.

What topology is $C^{\infty}_c$ equipped with?

That the space of compactly supported smooth functions (with the topology of test functions) is dense (with continuous embedding) in the space of Schwartz functions is proved on page 190 of Rudin's Functional Analysis. Like the above commenter mentioned, it may depend on what topology you have on $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but I would expect that the notion of convergence you mentioned coincides with convergence in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R^n})$ (the space of test functions).

@OttoBaier Thank you for your comments. I realized that I misunderstood the meaning of convergence of sequence of functions in $C_c^\infty(R^n)$ space. Yes, the convergence is in the sense of test functions as in the Definition 3.7 in [link] (https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m218a_09/ch3.pdf). Everything looks good now. Thanks:)
